# Firebase 3.3.x Nodejs - createUserWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've seen a lot of questions about this, but what confuses me is on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) of `firebase` **x** `nodejs` there is a function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`.

Everytime I print `firebase.auth()` it only has these functions :

```
{ 
    createCustomToken: [Function],
    verifyIdToken: [Function],
    INTERNAL:{ 
        delete: [Function],
        getToken: [Function],
        addAuthTokenListener: [Function],
        removeAuthTokenListener: [Function] 
    } 
}
```

Also, under the same nodejs documentation, the [firebase.auth()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth) says :

> auth(app) returns **firebase.auth.Auth**
>
> Gets the Auth object for the default App or a given App.
>
> Usage:
>
> firebase.auth() firebase.auth(app)

So I assumed that calling `firebase.auth()` will return [firebase.auth.Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth) which supposedly contains the [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) function.

**NOTE**

Yes, I properly initialized firebase using `firebase.initializeApp()` and it is working properly, Im already doing `database` transactions JSYK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Firebase SDK for Node.js can work in two modes (since version 3.3):

1. **as a server-side SDK, which happens when you initialize it work a service account**

   ```
   firebase.initializeApp({
     serviceAccount: "myproject-3d9889aaeddb.json",
     databaseURL: "https://myproject.firebaseio.com"
   });
   ```

   If you initialize with a service account (the only option available in version 3.2 and before), your connection will automatically be authenticated as an admin and you will only have [admin auth functionality](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/) available: creating and verifying custom tokens.
2. **as a client-side SDK, which happens when you initialize it work an API key**

   ```
   firebase.initializeApp({
     apiKey: "myprojectsApiKey",
     databaseURL: "https://myproject.firebaseio.com"
   });
   ```

   If you initialize with an API key (only possible since version 3.3), you will find the [client-side authentication methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) available.

It just verified this in a project of my own:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AI...Sc",
  databaseURL: "https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com"
});

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword("nodeuser@firebaseui.com", "firebase")
    .then(user => console.log(user))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

See [this post on firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/_6Rhro3zBbk/u8hB1oVRCgAJ) for full details.

Comment: I removed the `serviceAccount` in the initialization of the app and it worked. Thanks Frank, that's a lot of help. <3

Comment: I actually didn't know how it worked either, so it was fun to figure out.

Comment: I haven't checked it yet but my guess is, the `firebase.auth()` returns different object depending if the user/server is authenticated. So adding and/or removing the `serviceAccount` causes it. 

Again thanks Frank.

Comment: Is there a way to have both initialized, I need the service account for some other parts that are admin only access?