# Firebase function signInWithCustomToken undefined with Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I've created a custom token as such

```
const token = authRef.createCustomToken(options.userId, {
    app: appRootName,
    debug: !!options.debug
});
```

And then attempt to sign it in as such

```
return authRef.signInWithCustomToken(token).then((user) => {
    return user;
});
```

Custom creation token succeeds, but signInWithCustomToken spits out this error.

```
TypeError: authRef.signInWithCustomToken is not a function
```

This is Firebase 3 for nodejs and the service account has been set up. The app was properly initialized (or token generation wouldn't work in the first place), what's the issue here?

Comment: If you initialize Firebase in your Node.js script with a service account, you're already authenticated as an admin. To get the client-side sign-in option, initialize your Firebase app with an API key instead. See this answer for details/samples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347591/firebase-3-3-x-nodejs-createuserwithemailandpassword-is-not-a-function/39358227#39358227

Comment: Is there a way to interchange between the 2 modes in one application? This is just being done for testing purposes and not actual app usage. I've tried changing the name of initializeapp, but that seems to not work at all.

Comment: Even when **you** would use that only for testing, someone else will not realize than and end up minting custom tokens in a client-side app. I simply have separate `createCustomToken.js` and `signInWithCustomToken.js` node scripts.

Comment: It's code that wouldn't even exist in the client side app. It's for automated testing that isn't released with the application. I'll just look into generating the tokens in another place.

Comment: `console.log(auth.createCustomToken("puf", { isAdmin: true, isAwesome: "no, that is Abe" }))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actual issue is that

`authWithCustomToken`

exists in `firebase` and not in `firebase-admin` which is mostly used when using firebase security features.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, hope the following code can solve your problem.
Be careful using apiKey or serverKey

```
var firebase = require('firebase')
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: '*******',
    databaseURL: 'https://*****.firebaseio.com'
})

var customToken = '*********'
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken).catch(function(error) {
    var errorMessage = error.message
    console.log(errorMessage)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when deployed using a CI/CD pipeline. Worked fine when directly deployed to firebase from my local. Both approaches uses same token to deploy. I am using `firebase-admin` latest version, i.e., 5.11.0.

The only solution I found is to

1. Set the keys to cloud functions config, e.g., `firebase functions:config:set  custom.apikey=KEY_HERE`,
2. Read the keys inside the cloud function that renders the page and set to the firebase config retrieved via `functions.config().firebase`,

BTW, we are rendering the pages via `nextjs` which is hosted in a google cloud function. This rendered page communicates with the firebase firestore database.