# Error when validating firebase token: `TypeError: firebase.auth(...).verifyIdToken is not a function`

Tags: node.js, firebase, token, firebase-authentication

I am trying to verify id tokens generated on the front end in my nodejs app. I am following [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/verify-id-tokens) guide.

The token is generated fine. I save it as a cookie. I can print it to the nodejs console. When I try to validate it, I get this error:

```
TypeError: firebase.auth(...).verifyIdToken is not a function
    at router.get (/home/marcel/code/clairitech/website/routes/index.js:30:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/marcel/code/clairitech/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/marcel/code/clairitech/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/marcel/code/clairitech/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/marcel/code/clairitech/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/marcel/code/clairitech/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/marcel/code/clairitech/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/home/marcel/code/clairitech/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/marcel/code/clairitech/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/home/marcel/code/clairitech/website/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
```

Here is my code:

```
const firebase = require('firebase').initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDLT76jVp0F2_fqbvV8azRz3HybD-****",
  authDomain: "****.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://****.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "****.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "******"
}, 'admin')
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(req.cookies.firebase_token).then(token => {
      console.log('token:')
      console.log(token)
    }).catch(err => { throw err })
})
```

I am using firebase 3.4.1 from npm and node version 6.2.2.

Edit 1: Added firebase config.

Comment: *How* you initialize your app is quite crucial to how this works. Please share how you initialize your config. If you're anxious about sharing the config values (you shouldn't be btw, these config values are meant to be shared publicly), just blank those out. Reason I'm asking is that the node.js SDK has two modes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347591/firebase-3-3-x-nodejs-createuserwithemailandpassword-is-not-a-function/39358227#39358227

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added that now. The reason I was hesitant is because I signed a confidentiality contract. I was told I am not even allowed to tell anyone we are using firebase (I know its ridiculous, like I said we use firebase on the front end).

Comment: OK. Thanks for the additional info. You're initializing the Firebase client with an API key, which means it switches to "client side node.js mode". In that mode the server-side APIs (such as `verifyIdToken`) are not available. To get those methods, initialize Firebase with a service account as shown in approach 1 in the linked answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't see where to download the json file

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#server-sdk-authentication

Comment: I figured it out. It was actually https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup that helped the most.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to reference firebase

```
var firebase = require('firebase').initializeApp(config);
......
```

Comment: That what I had. I don't know why I put that.

Comment: You mean you tried it and it's not working for you?

Comment: Yes. That is what I have and that is what is giving the error.

Comment: Without it gives a different error.

Comment: Do you also have the `config` set? config is an object containing information to connect to your firebase

Comment: Yes I have config set. I didn't post it for obvious reasons...