# Why firebase auth methods are gone when code runs on server under [client] credentials?

Tags: node.js, firebase, openshift, firebase-authentication

Code for our Node server app works perfectly when we use [client config] for creating the firebase app obj (Image_1) this works locally when debugging with vs code (localhost); In this scenario all methods for auth are there; Now, after uploading to our gear at (OpenShfit), we get a "TypeError: auth.applyActionCode is not a function" error. This happens whether we use [client config] or [server config] credentials for initializing the firebase app object.

Everything else is working on the server, real time database works perfectly with [server config] (service credentials). Only the auth object seems to lose its methods when running in the server. We double checked that all source code and node_modules are identical in the client and the server.

SDK is 3.4.1-rc.2.

When uploading to server the methods for the auth object are gone. I have also set the service account with the "owner" role and it didn't work either.

Here is our code:

[image]

Image_1: We set the this.firebaseClientConfig and this.firebaseServerConfig private vars.

[image]
Image_2: Start method receives a string which depending on value will initialize the firebase instance using the client or server config/stop method is called after operation is completed, so when another operation is required it can use client or server config.

[image]
Image_3: the getDb method works perfeclty, the getAuth method returns an auth object that only has methods when run with client config at localhost.

[image]
Image_4: Sample code from a service that actually works on localhost and server (access to rt db).

[image]
Image_5: This just won't work on the server (auth object doesn't have methods) , however it works at localhost.

[image]
Image_6: Works on localhost.

[image]
Image_7: @ Production :(

Comment: The Firebase JavaScript Server SDK has two modes: one for node.js servers and one for IoT-like client-side devices. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347591/firebase-3-3-x-nodejs-createuserwithemailandpassword-is-not-a-function/39358227#39358227

Comment: A few comments to help you get better answers: 1) don't include screenshots of code or other text, include the actual text. 2) you seem to be describing the solution you can't get to work, it's better if you describe the use-case you're trying to implement. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, Thanks Frank, what you describe in your post is correct, firebase has two modes of initialization, in which the auth object behaves different. As you can see in the screenshots (sorry for using screenshots instead of actual code, my reasoning was that it would be a lot easier to undestand due to syntax coloring, my bad), I have two configurations available, client or server, I use server (which uses the provided service account) for web services in the project that need some db manipulation, client (which only works in localhost) for auth. It won't work on the server.(??)

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, I have fixed the question title, as it stated that the problem was with server credentials, this was my bad, as the problem is that there are no auth methods in our scenario whether you use client or server config.

Answer (score 0):

If you are instantiating a client and admin instance. Make sure you use a different app ID for each:

```
case 'client':
  this.fbInstance = firebase.initializeApp({...}, 'client');
  ...
case 'server'
  this.fbInstance = firebase.initializeApp({...}, 'server');
  ...
```

Otherwise the second instance will actually fail and throw an error which you seem to catch and suppress. This will then fail when getAuth() is called on it.